# Laravel - Creating API tokens to use internally for each user

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-passport

Every `user` of my application may use the API **only within the application** with Vue. The old `api_token` solution works for me, but it seems to be insecure since the `api_token` is the only thing that separates the user from the data.

I've read about Passport that uses OAuth2 methodology which is far more secure than a simple `api_token`.

Is there a way to use Passport to achieve this? Note that every time a `user` is created, I must create a API token to him.

We have no plans to open this API for external applications.

Comment: If it's within the same application then the session is probably good enough. No need to over-engineer it.

Comment: You mean without `api_token`? API routes does not store Session.

Comment: I mean if it's within the same application only and not going to be exposed to the world then it's not really an API so you could just use the session and normal routes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Using Vue without an API? I don't think so. You are missing that I can't set everything up on my page load, I have to make request to retrieve/modify my data.

Comment: The request follows the same origin rules. If the request is made from your own page then the cookies are sent to the server and there's no CORS issues coming up so the session is a perfectly reasonable option here. You can also use the "remember token" to keep a user signed in via cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create tokens for every user, have a look at below code.

```
// find specific user
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;

// Creating a token with scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['place-orders'])->accessToken;
```

you can create token after user creation too, just add logic of token after a user has been created.

Comment: `createToken` is not a function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the trait `HasApiTokens`. Now I can create tokens.

Comment: OK, I've read about this function at Laravel documentation but couldn't figure out about how to test my API with Postman. How should I do that?