# how to fetch personal access token in laravel's Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to secure my api with laravel's passport, I can get the password type access token but i can't seem to get the personal access token, i wanna use the personal access token so my token won't be expired,
 what should i put in the grant type ?
 Thank you

Comment: see the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client here

Comment: thank you for your answer Vishal but i read it and i couldn't find what i was looking for , i want to follow the same request but for getting personal access token i think i should keep everything except the client_id and the secret which gonna be those of the personal access token , i don't know what to put in the grant type

Comment: Check this here code is creating permanent token for specific user, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761716/3584881