# Laravel passport authentication and token generation

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

I am new to Laravel, just started building REST APIs. I have started from creating login and registration APIs. For user authentication, I have used PASSPORT of Laravel. I have performed a number of steps defined at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#installation. Everything is going well expect core functionality. I have migrated tables, I am able to see routes list by `$ php artisan route:list`. But I am facing issue at where I am trying to generate a token with the help of `oauth/token`.

This is the POST data what I am sending to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token

    {
    "client_id": 2, //from oauth_clients table
    "client_secret": "XcYUuFDOtWByLPOdrQbW5rEf9tWBqoToPgJVAA3L", //from oauth_clients table
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "adnmin@test.com", //saved in users table
    "password": "$2y$10$4fJz1/DA2mFg.McFfCqrkuXm1/wojQQh3eM4EEkbLjclGb4nETRy2", //saved in users table
    "scope": "*"
}
```

I am continually getting *invalid_credinatials*. I am not able to understand what is the parameter to be sent to the place of username and password.

Comment: you can create token for a specific user like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761716/3584881)

Comment: Is this related to passport authentication?

Comment: yes, its for creating token for a single user and that token can be used in future API calls.

Comment: You need to pass the plain password, not the hashed password that's stored in the users table.

Comment: Thanks, @RisanBagjaPradana it has taken my lots of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password saved in the database is in the encrypted form, so you have to give the actual password there, as Laravel automatically encrypts your password.